# Crossbow or Harpoon?

Tags: technology

is a crossbow with an iron arrow and a rope linked to it a harpoon, or a crossbow with other ammory.

(Inspired by the series Dirk Gentlys, Episode 6 where the cop calls it a harpoon instead of a crossbow)

Thx for help!

Comment: A _crossbow_ is a device which launches a projectile. A _harpoon_ is a projectile, wich can be launched by hand, gun or crossbow.

Comment: I don't understand the question? Or see one, for that matter.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! We are dedicated to helping people build fictional worlds and the elements therein. It looks like you have a question about a definition of the harpoon in the real world. This is off-topic on WorldBuilding. Is there something we could help you with? Otherwise I think this question should be closed as off-topic. If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn about how this site works. Have fun!

Comment: the question would be better asked on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A harpoon is any projectile with a barbed head and a line tied to it. This allows the projectile to remain embedded in the prey while the line is used to remain connected to the prey (fish it out of water for smaller fish, wear out and retrieve for whales). How the harpoon is launched is irrelevant. Crossbows aren't usually used for harpoons, but there's no intrinsic reason why it's impossible.

Comment: @Sly321 - I appreciate the selection, but you should not generally choose so quickly. Leave at least 24 hours before making your choice. After all, someone might (perish the thought!) come up with a better answer, or even establish that my answer is - inadequate.